# PyArrow SIGSEGV error when using UnionDatasets

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

**The context**:
I am using PyArrow to read a folder structured as `exchange/symbol/date.parquet`. The folder contains multiple exchanges, multiple symbols and multiple files. At the time I am writing the folder is about 30GB/1.85M files.

If I use a single PyArrow `Dataset` to read/manage the entire folder, the simplest process with just the dataset defined will occupy 2.3GB of RAM. The problem is, I am instanciating this dataset on multiple processes but since every process only needs some exchanges (typically just one), I don't need to read all folders and files in every single process.

So I tried to use a `UnionDataset` composed of single exchange `Dataset`. In this way, every process just loads the required folder/files as a dataset. By a simple test, by doing so every process now occupy just 868MB of RAM, -63%.

**The problem**:
When using a single `Dataset` for the entire folder/files, I have no problem at all. I can read filtered data without problems and it's fast as duck.

But when I read the `UnionDataset` filtered data, I always get `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)` error. So after looking every single source of the problem, I noticed that if I create a dummy folder with multiple exchanges but just some symbols, in order to limit the files amout to read, I don't get that error and it works normally. If I then copy new symbols folders (any) I get again that error.

I came up thinking that the problem is not about my code, but linked instead to the amout of files that the UnionDataset is able to manage.

Am I correct or am I doing something wrong? Thank you all, have a nice day and good work.

Comment: This is very useful information.  However, this sounds like a bug.  Pyarrow should never generate SIGSEGV.  I would highly encourage you to file a JIRA ticket.

Comment: Well, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @ilpomo if you have a code snippet that is able to reproduce the SIGSEGV, you can go to https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/ and fill a new Jira issue for Apache Arrow. Attaching the code snippet that causes the problem will greatly speed up the resolution.

Comment: @amol done (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-15045), hope it get fixed as soon as possibile since this is blocking my development. Unfortunately at the moment I cannot create a simple script to reproduce the bug, since it's dependent on those .parquet files.